# fetch only 1 object data and store to model with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http, httprequest, response

i have the response from http request like this:

```
{
    "alamat1": "",
    "alamat2": "",
    "alamat3": "",
    "branch_name": "",
    "can_void": ,
    "def_servicechg": ,
    "def_tax": ,
    "email": "",
```

Anyone can tell me how to store it to model data automatically and call back in another page with dart language?

Comment: This would help: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data

Comment: Do you have your modal?

Answer (score 0):

Define your model class like this with correct data types for the formats

```
class Details {
  final String? alamat1;
  final String? alamat2;
  final String? alamat3;
  final String? branch_name;
  final bool can_void;
  final double? def_servicechg;
  final double? def_tax;
  final String? email;

  Details(
      {required this.alamat1,
      required this.alamat2,
      required this.alamat3,
      required this.branch_name,
      required this.can_void,
      required this.def_servicechg,
      required this.def_tax,
      required this.email});

  factory Details.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return Details(
        alamat1: parsedJson["alamat1"],
        alamat2: parsedJson["alamat2"],
        alamat3: parsedJson["alamat3"],
        branch_name: parsedJson["branch_name"],
        can_void: parsedJson["can_void"],
        def_servicechg: parsedJson["def_servicechg"],
        def_tax: parsedJson['def_tax'],
        email: parsedJson["email"]);
  }
}
```

And in your HTTP response, you can use the data type like this

```
List<Details> data = [];
for (var element in response) {
   data.add(Details.fromJson(element));
}
```

or

```
List<Details> data = [];
data = response.map(element => Details.fromJson(element));
```

And the callback on another page means? is there any relation between pages or not? But you can use any state management packages like BLoC or GetX or river pod.